# Apache custom module, where to put its own log file?

Tags: apache, logfiles, apache-modules, file-security

I have a Apache module that acts as a security filter that allows requests to pass or not. This is a custom made module, I don't want to use any existent module.

I have actually two questions:

1. The module has its own log file. I'm thinking that the best location should be in **/var/log/apache2/** but since the Apache process runs on www-data user, it cannot create files on that path. I want to find a solution for the log file in such way that is not much intrusive (in terms of security) for a typical web server. Where would be the best place and what kind of security attributes should be set?
2. The module communicates with another process using pipes. I would like to spawn this process from Apache module only when I need it. Where should I locate this binary and how should I set the privileges as less intrusive as possible?

Thanks,
Cezane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache starts under the superuser first and performs the module initialization (calling the `module_struct::register_hooks` function). There you can create the log files and either `chown` them to `www-data` or keep the file descriptor open in order to later use it from the `fork`ed and `setuid`ed worker processes.

(And if you need an alternative, I think it's also possible to log with `syslog` and configure it to route your log messages to your log file).

Under the worker process you are already running as the `www-data` user so there isn't much you can do to further secure the execution. For example, AFAIK, you can't `setuid` to yet another user or `chroot` to protect the filesystem.

What you *can* do to improve the security is to use a system firewall. For example, under AppArmor you could tell the operating system what binaries your Apache module can execute, stopping it from executing any unwanted binaries. And you can limit that binary's filesystem access, preventing it from accessing `www-data` files that doesn't belong to it.

Comment: I forgot that firstly Apache starts as root. And I though register_hooks (especially child_init) is called after the fork in order to initialize the module. I'll check this out. Thanks a lot for the hint!

Comment: Yeah, the function registered with `ap_hook_child_init` runs after `setuid`, but the `register_hooks` function runs as `root`.